# How to (step-by-step) retrieve a picture from the iPhone contact list?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4S allows me to get to any contact on the list and edit it -- no surprise, so far. It allows me (on edit mode) to copy the picture of my contact. I apply my finger on the picture and small tabs come on: one says "copy" and the other says "paste". I press my finger on the "copy" tab. How and where can I paste it in order to be able to transfer that picture somewhere else?

I've tried to paste the picture on the Photos / Camera Roll, to no avail. I've read instructions on how to get to my Home folder/Application Support/AddressBook/Images to try and find the picture I am looking for. The funny thing is... I've synced my iPhone all along on this computer and it only shows one item on the Images folder -- the Apple icon.

I've connected the iPhone to the same computer and then couldn't find a way of getting to the pictures from the contact list. Any step-by-step approach on how to sync the iPhone and the AddressBook, leaving aside the computerese gobbledeegook, would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think of it as being on the same clipboard that copied text goes to.

Answer (score 1):

After you've copied the image from the address book, paste it into an email to yourself. You can then access your email from a computer and download the image.